# How to pipe list of files returned by find command to cat to view all the files

Tags: unix, find, pipe

I am doing a [`find`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to get a list of files.

How do I pipe it to another utility like [`cat`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) so that `cat` displays the contents of all those files?

Afterwards, I'd use [`grep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) on that to search some text in those files.

Answer (score 413, accepted):

1. Piping to another process (although this **won't** accomplish what you said you are trying to do):

   ```
    command1 | command2
   ```

   This will send the output of command1 as the input of command2.
2. `-exec` on a `find` (this will do what you want to do, but it's specific to `find`):

   ```
    find . -name '*.foo' -exec cat {} \;
   ```

   Everything between `find` and `-exec` are the find predicates you were already using. `{}` will substitute the particular file you found into the command (`cat {}` in this case); the `\;` is to end the `-exec` command.
3. Send output of one process as command line arguments to another process:

   ```
    command2 `command1`
   ```

   For example:

   ```
    cat `find . -name '*.foo' -print`
   ```

   Note these are [backquotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick) not regular quotes (they are under the tilde <kbd>~</kbd> on my keyboard).

   This will send the output of `command1` into `command2` as command line arguments. It's called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). Note that file names containing spaces (newlines, etc) will be broken into separate arguments, though.

Comment: cat `find -name '*.foo' -print` worked great for me ... Thanks

Comment: The backquotes work great and is more generalized, you can use this to cat a list of files from a file as well.

Comment: Note that modern versions of `find` allow you to write: `find . -name '*.foo' -exec cat {} +`, where the `+` indicates that `find` should group as many file names as convenient into a single command invocation.  This is quite useful (it deals with spaces etc in file names without resorting to `-print0` and `xargs -0`).

Comment: the exec() also works for grep  (find . -name '*.foo' -exec grep bar {} \;)

Comment: Unmentioned: `find . -name '*.foo' | xargs cat`

Comment: cat `find . -name '*.foo' -print` . This variant hang when no file exist.

Comment: Just to add on @stewSquared s answer: To find all lines in files that contain a certain string, do `find . -name '*.foo' | xargs cat | grep string`

Comment: @Bim i was looking for that, but when i add `grep mystring` its not finding my string, returning empty (centos6).

Comment: @blamb It worked for me on Debian / Ubuntu. Maybe try "xargs grep foo", or the modern version below...

Answer (score 102):

#### Modern version

POSIX 2008 added the `+` marker to [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) which means it now automatically groups as many files as are reasonable into a single command execution, very much like `xargs` does, but with a number of advantages:

1. You don't have to worry about odd characters in the file names.
2. You don't have to worry about the command being invoked with zero file names.

The file name issue is a problem with `xargs` without the `-0` option, and the 'run even with zero file names' issue is a problem with or without the `-0` option — but GNU `xargs` has the `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` option to prevent that happening.  Also, this notation cuts down on the number of processes, not that you're likely to measure the difference in performance. Hence, you could sensibly write:

```
find . -exec grep something {} +
```

#### Classic version

```
find . -print | xargs grep something
```

If you're on Linux or have the GNU `find` and `xargs` commands, then use `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs` to handle file names containing spaces and other odd-ball characters.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 grep something
```

#### Tweaking the results from `grep`

If you don't want the file names (just the text) then add an appropriate option to `grep` (usually `-h` to suppressing 'headings').  To absolutely guarantee the file name is printed by `grep` (even if only one file is found, or the last invocation of `grep` is only given 1 file name), then add `/dev/null` to the `xargs` command line, so that there will always be at least two file names.

Comment: For those confused like I am, note that this way will first give all the output of find, and then give the output of `xargs grep something`.

Comment: @EricHu: I can see you are confused, but it does not do what you say it does, at least not on any Unix-based system I know of. The output of `find` is piped to the standard input of `xargs`. The `xargs` program reads its standard input, splitting the input at white space (blanks, newlines, tabs, etc) and appends a number of the words to the command `grep something` and executes the command line. `xargs` then continues reading input and executing commands until it runs out of input. `xargs` runs the `grep` command as often as necessary for the input it is given (from `find` in this example).

Comment: Ah my mistake, this is using grep to search within each file matched.  I was looking to simply filter the output of find with grep

Comment: That you can do by dropping the `xargs` from the pipeline, sending the output of `find` direct to `grep`.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually what I was trying before I searched for this.  I guess `find` outputs errors to something other than standard out?  The `2>/dev/null` param for flag was what I needed

Comment: Errors go to standard error (file descriptor 2) on all well-behaved commands.  Redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` loses the error messages.

Comment: This is also has the benefit that it works better with spaces in the file path. Even 'sed'ing " " -> "\ " breaks it with the ` but with xargs it works perfectly

Comment: @JZL003 when i try it with sed, i get "illegal byte sequence" from sed.

Answer (score 46):

There are a few ways to pass the list of files returned by the `find` command to the `cat` command, though technically not all use piping, and none actually pipe directly to `cat`.

1. The simplest is to use backticks (`` ` ``):

   ```
   cat `find [whatever]`
   ```

   This takes the output of `find` and effectively places it on the command line of `cat`. This doesn't work well if `find` has too much output (more than can fit on a command-line) or if the output has special characters (like spaces).
2. In some shells, including `bash`, one can use `$()` instead of backticks :

   ```
   cat $(find [whatever])
   ```

   This is less portable, but is nestable. Aside from that, it has pretty much the same caveats as backticks.
3. Because running other commands on what was found is a common use for `find`, find has an `-exec` action which executes a command for each file it finds:

   ```
   find [whatever] -exec cat {} \;
   ```

   The `{}` is a placeholder for the filename, and the `\;` marks the end of the command (It's possible to have other actions after `-exec`.)

   This will run `cat` once for every single file rather than running a single instance of `cat` passing it multiple filenames which can be inefficient and might not have the behavior you want for some commands (though it's fine for `cat`). The syntax is also a awkward to type -- you need to escape the semicolon because semicolon is special to the shell!
4. Some versions of `find` (most notably the GNU version) let you replace `;` with `+` to use `-exec`'s append mode to run fewer instances of `cat`:

   ```
   find [whatever] -exec cat {} +
   ```

   This will pass multiple filenames to each invocation of `cat`, which can be more efficient.

   Note that this is *not* guaranteed to use a single invocation, however. If the command line would be too long then the arguments are spread across multiple invocations of `cat`. For `cat` this is probably not a big deal, but for some other commands this may change the behavior in undesirable ways. On Linux systems, the command line length limit is quite large, so splitting into multiple invocations is quite rare compared to some other OSes.
5. The classic/portable approach is to use `xargs`:

   ```
   find [whatever] | xargs cat
   ```

   `xargs` runs the command specified (`cat`, in this case), and adds arguments based on what it reads from stdin. Just like `-exec` with `+`, this will break up the command-line if necessary. That is, if `find` produces too much output, it'll run `cat` multiple times. As mentioned in the section about `-exec` earlier, there are some commands where this splitting may result in different behavior. Note that using `xargs` like this has issues with spaces in filenames, as `xargs` just uses whitespace as a delimiter.
6. The most robust, portable, and efficient method also uses `xargs`:

   ```
   find [whatever] -print0 | xargs -0 cat
   ```

   The `-print0` flag tells `find` to use `\0` (null character) delimiters between filenames, and the `-0` flag tells `xargs` to expect these `\0` delimiters. This has pretty much identical behavior to the `-exec`...`+` approach, though is more portable (but unfortunately more verbose).

Comment: The backtick method is great, because it works for other commands like `ls`, too.

Comment: @Martin Braun using `$()` Also works with commands other than `find `.

Comment: Thanks, good to know, I kinda stopped reading after (1), because it serves my needs, since I'm not dealing with special characters like spaces and such.

Answer (score 11):

To achieve this (using bash) I would do as follows:

```
cat $(find . -name '*.foo')
```

This is known as the "command substitution" and it strips line feed by default which is really convinient !

more infos [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a job for a shell script to me:

```
for file in 'find -name *.xml'
do
   grep 'hello' file
done
```

or something like that

Comment: This is a valid, though not necessarily optimal, answer to the question.

Comment: ...yeah but it is great if you want one big file with filenames listed as well.

Comment: I like this the best. A loop block like this leaves room to do other things.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my way to find file names that contain some content that I'm interested in, just a single bash line that nicely handles spaces in filenames too:

```
find . -name \*.xml | while read i; do grep '<?xml' "$i" >/dev/null; [ $? == 0 ] && echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 3):

The find command has an -exec argument that you can use for things like this, you could just do the grep directly using that.

For example ([from here, other good examples at this page](http://www.athabascau.ca/html/depts/compserv/webunit/HOWTO/find.htm#EX03)):

```
find . -exec grep "www.athabasca" '{}' \; -print
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my shot for general use:

```
grep YOURSTRING `find .`
```

It will print the file name

Answer (score 2):

In bash, the following would be appropriate:

```
find /dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0i cat {} | grep whatever
```

This will find all files in the `/dir` directory, and safely pipe the filenames into `xargs`, which will safely drive `grep`.

Skipping `xargs` is not a good idea if you have many thousands of files in `/dir`; `cat` will break due to excessive argument list length. `xargs` will sort that all out for you.

The `-print0` argument to `find` meshes with the `-0` argument to `xargs` to handle filenames with spaces properly. The `-i` argument to `xargs` allows you to insert the filename where required in the `cat` command line.  The brackets are replaced by the filename piped into the `cat` command from `find`.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this:

```
find . -name <filename> -print0 | xargs -0 cat | grep <word2search4>
```

"`-print0`" argument for "find" and "`-0`" argument for "xargs" are needed to handle whitespace in file paths/names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```bsh
find _CACHE_* | while read line; do
    cat "$line" | grep "something"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ggrep](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/ggrep/).

```
ggrep -H -R -I "mysearchstring" *
```

to search for a file in unix containing text located in the current directory or a subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

This will print the name and contents of files-only recursively..

```
find . -type f -printf '\n\n%p:\n' -exec cat {} \;
```

**Edit (Improved version):**
This will print the name and contents of text (ascii) files-only recursively..

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print | xargs awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME ":" $0; }'
```

One more attempt

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -printf "\n%p:" -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to find text in files?  You can simply use grep for that...

```
grep searchterm *
```

Answer (score -1):

To list and see contents of all abc.def files on a server in the directories /ghi and /jkl

```
find /ghi /jkl -type f -name abc.def 2> /dev/null -exec ls {} \; -exec cat {} \;
```

To list the abc.def files which have commented entries and display see those entries in the directories /ghi and /jkl

```
find /ghi /jkl -type f -name abc.def 2> /dev/null -exec grep -H ^# {} \;
```