# Bash Script to Generate .css from .less Files Using lessc

Tags: linux, bash, less

I'm looking to write a bash script that will recursively find all `.less` files in a directory and create a `.css` file with the same name in a parent `css` directory using `lessc`.  Visually it looks like this.

Before:

```
/css
/less
    a.less
    b.less
/whatever
    /css
    /less
        c.less
        d.less
```

After:

```
/css
    a.css
    b.css
/less
    a.less
    b.less
/whatever
    /css
        c.css
        d.css
    /less
        c.less
        d.less
```

What I've been able to figure out so far is that I can find all the files using:

```
find . -name *.less
```

And I can generate individual files using:

```
lessc foo.less > ../css/foo.css
```

My problem comes trying to pipe the results of the `find` into `lessc`.  Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864316/how-to-pipe-list-of-files-returned-by-find-command-to-cat-to-view-all-the-files) I can see how the results of `find` can be piped into `cat`, but the same approach isn't working for me with `lessc`.

In general I'm just having trouble putting the pieces together.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit**

This is what worked for me.  Thanks @ghoti!

```
find . -name \*.less -print | sed -rne 's:(.*)/less/([^/]+).less$:lessc & > \1/css/\2.css:p' | sh
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got all the ingredients.  You just need the recipe.  :-)

And there are multiple recipes.

Normally, you can use `find`'s `-exec` option to execute things based on what it finds.  However, you're limited in what you can name things.  For example, if you were to use this:

```
find . -name \*.less -exec lessc {} ../css/{}.css
```

you would create files in a css directory in the parent from where find is running, and files would be named things like a.less.css, b.less.css, etc.  That's not good.  You'd need to embed `dirname` and such into your command, and then things get impossible to manage, with too many quotes and backslashes.

When I have to do pattern-matting AND changes like this, I often resort to pipes.  Here's what I'd do:

```
find . -name \*.less -print | \
  sed -rne 's:(.*)/less/([^/]+).less$:lessc & > \1/css/\2.css:p'
```

The `find` gets your files, as you'd expect.  Then the `sed` script turns them into command lines.  The output of this is a collection of `lessc` command lines which you can simply pipe into `sh` once you've verified that they look right.

Here are the results.

Before:

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ find . -type f -print
./whatever/less/c.less
./whatever/less/d.less
./less/a.less
./less/b.less
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$
```

Then the test run:

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ find . -name \*.less -print | sed -rne 's:(.*)/less/([^/]+).less$:cat & > \1/css/\2.css:p'
cat ./whatever/less/c.less > ./whatever/css/c.css
cat ./whatever/less/d.less > ./whatever/css/d.css
cat ./less/a.less > ./css/a.css
cat ./less/b.less > ./css/b.css
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$
```

Then the final run, and results.

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ find . -name \*.less -print | sed -rne 's:(.*)/less/([^/]+).less$:cat & > \1/css/\2.css:p' | sh
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ find . -type f -print
./css/b.css
./css/a.css
./whatever/less/c.less
./whatever/less/d.less
./whatever/css/d.css
./whatever/css/c.css
./less/a.less
./less/b.less
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$
```

For my test, I replaced `lessc` with `cat`, since less isn't installed on my workstation.

Note that this will only work with simple filenames like the ones in your example.  If you have spaces or possibly other "special" characters, it will break.

Comment: Also just as an fyi for anyone else that happens to see this apparently the ```-r``` option for ```sed``` isn't supported on OS X, but you can substitute it with ```-E``` (http://www.flashesofpanic.com/panic/002596.php).

Comment: @TJVanToll - good point; I used the `-r` option in my answer because the question is tagged `linux`.  The `-E` option derives from older versions of FreeBSD's sed, on which OSX's sed is based.  In newer FreeBSD, sed includes the `-r` option *as well*, for easier interoperability with GNU sed.  For anyone else reading this, if you're using an operating system whose `sed` does not include an option for ERE, then you'll have to translate the regex to BRE.  Or ask how to do it on StackOverflow.  :)

Comment: Thanks again.  The script is eventually going to have to run on a linux box but I was testing it out on OS X so I thought I'd include that tidbit in case anyone randomly Googles this in the future.

Comment: For posterity, `'s:(.*)/less/([^/]+).less$:cat & > \1/css/\2.css:p'`, in basic RE looks like `'s:\(.*\)/less/\([^/][^/]*\).less$:cat & > \1/css/\2.css:p'`.  Backreferences (`\1` and `\2`) should work the same in every sed implementation.

Comment: Is it possible to get this running in a shell script? I've tweaked it a bit, but nothing seems to work

Comment: @AJMaxwell - sure, it should work in a shell script.  If you're having trouble getting your shell script running, I recommend [asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) tagged for whatever shell you're using, and the tools that are causing difficulties.  In your question, be sure to include your existing script and the complete errors you're seeing.

Comment: @ghoti - I got the script working. It turns out my installation of `lessc` was pooched. After uninstalling/re-installing a number of packages, I got everything working again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop

```
for file in $(find . -name *.less)
do
    css="${file//less/css}"
    mkdir -p $(dirname "$css")
    lessc "$file" > "$css"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  When I run this I'm getting the following error (once per ```.less``` file).  

```../css/./less/FILE_NAME.css: No such file or directory```

Answer (score 0):

If your .css file is in the `D:\demo` folder, create a file `convert.bat` containing:

```
$ d:
$ cd demo
$ lessc style.less style.css
```

When you run this file, it will convert .less to .css.