# How to cat multiple files from a list of files in Bash?

Tags: file, bash, loops

I have a text file that holds a list of files. I want to `cat` their contents together.  What is the best way to do this?  I was doing something like this but it seems overly complex:

```
let count=0
while read -r LINE
do
    [[ "$line" =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue
    if [ $count -ne 0 ] ; then
        file="$LINE"
        while read PLINE
        do
            echo $PLINE | cat - myfilejs > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out myfile.js
        done < $file
    fi
    let count++
done < tmp
```

I was skipping commented lines and running into issues. There has to be a better way to do this, without two loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Or in a simple command

```
cat $(grep -v '^#' files) > output
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I doubt that for this particular application one would really use space-separated filenames. Rather propose an improvement, as in my opinion a oneliner is a nicer solution than a 8-line script. Are you actually using filenames with whitespace EVER?

Comment: @Bernhard Don't take this the wrong way, but *of course* we deal with filenames with whitespace all the time. We support users who don't know the difference, and why should they if it's easy enough to write a script that can handle it?

Comment: And if didn't have comments: `cat $(cat files) > output`

Answer (score 8):

**`xargs cat < files`**

The advantage of xargs over `$(cat)` is that `cat` expands to a huge list of arguments which could fail if you have a lot of files in the list due to Linux' maximum command line length.

Example without caring about `#`:

```
printf 'a\nb\nc\n' > files
printf '12\n3\n' > a
printf '4\n56\n' > b
printf  '8\n9\n' > c
xargs cat < files
```

Output:

```
12
3
4
56
8
9
```

More specific example ignoring `#` as requested by OP:

```
printf 'a\nb\n#c\n' > files
printf '12\n3\n' > a
printf '4\n56\n' > b
printf  '8\n9\n' > c
grep -v '^#' files | xargs cat
```

Output:

```
12
3
4
56
```

Related: [How to pipe list of files returned by find command to cat to view all the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864316/how-to-pipe-list-of-files-returned-by-find-command-to-cat-to-view-all-the-files)

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()
while read; do
    case "$REPLY" in
        \#*|'') continue;;
        *) files+=( "$REPLY" );;
    esac
done < input
cat "${files[@]}"
```

What's better about this approach is that:

1. The only external command, `cat`, only gets executed once.
2. It's pretty careful to maintain significant whitespace for any given line/filename.

Comment: In comparison to this answer:
cat $(grep -v '^#' files) > output

Are there any obvious advantages?

Comment: @user1470511 Yes, the `grep` answer can break if any of the filenames have whitespace in them.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
  while read file
  do
    #process comments here with continue
    cat "$file"
  done
} < tmp > newfile
```

Comment: I fixed the use of the variable `file`. Is there a real need for the braces?

Comment: @chepner: No, since the variable use is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

How about `cat $(cat listoffiles) | grep -v "^#"`?

Comment: Don't you mean `cat $(grep -v '^#' listoffiles)`? What about whitespace issues?

Comment: OK, as long as none of the filenames contain spaces.

Comment: @chepner Or as long as whitespaces are escaped in `listoffiles`, or names quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
sed '/^$/d;/^#/d;s/^/cat "/;s/$/";/' files | sh > output
```

Steps:

1. *sed* removes blank lines & commented out lines from *files*.
2. *sed* then wraps each line in `cat "` and `";`.
3. Script is then piped to *sh* with and into *output*.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this crudely handles whitespaces by wrapping the file names in quotes.