# Snakemake cannot handle very long command line?

Tags: snakemake

This is a very strange problem.
When my `{input}` specified in the `rule` section is a list of <200 files, snakemake worked all right.
But when `{input}` has more than 500 files, snakemake just quitted with messages `(one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)`. The complete log did not provide any error messages.

For the log, please see: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/files/5285271/2020-09-25T151835.613199.snakemake.log

The rule that worked is (NOTE the `input` is capped to 200 files):

```
rule combine_fastq:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: samples.loc[(wildcards.sample), ["fq"]].dropna()[0].split(',')[:200]
    output:
        "combined.fastq/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    group: "minion_assemble"
    shell:
        """
echo {input} >  {output}
        """
```

The rule that failed is:

```
rule combine_fastq:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: samples.loc[(wildcards.sample), ["fq"]].dropna()[0].split(',')
    output:
        "combined.fastq/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    group: "minion_assemble"
    shell:
        """
echo {input} >  {output}
        """
```

My question is also posted in GitHub: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/643.

Comment: I think it might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit

Comment: I think the command line length in shell is not a problem. I ran `getconf ARG_MAX ` and got `4611686018427387903`.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande  I have not figured that. I wrote a different script to bypass this problem in snakemake.

Answer (score 2):

I second Maarten's answer, with that many files you are running up against a shell limit; snakemake is just doing a poor job helping you identify the problem.

Based on the issue you reference, it seems like you are using cat to combine all of your files.  Maybe following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619500/how-to-cat-multiple-files-from-a-list-of-files-in-bash) would help:

```py
rule combine_fastq_list:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: samples.loc[(wildcards.sample), ["fq"]].dropna()[0].split(',')
    output:
        temp("{sample}.tmp.list")
    group: "minion_assemble"
    script:
        with open(output[0]) as out:
            out.write('\n'.join(input))

rule combine_fastq:
    input:
        temp("{sample}.tmp.list")
    output:
        'combined.fastq/{sample}.fastq.gz'
    group: "minion_assemble"
    shell:
        'cat {input} | '  # this is reading the list of files from the file
            'xargs zcat -f | '
            '...'
```

Hope it gets you on the right track.

**edit**

The first option executes your command separately for each input file. A different option that executes the command once for the whole list of input is:

```
rule combine_fastq:
    ...
    shell:
        """
        command $(< {input}) ...
        """
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick. I tried but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: This didn't work for me like this, but with using the input directly as argument: `$(< {input.files})`!

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande can you edit my answer or post a new one? Not sure I know where to make that modification.

Answer (score 1):

For those landing here with similar questions (like [Snakemake expand function alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414327/snakemake-expand-function-alternative)), [snakemake 6](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html) can handle long command lines. The following test fails on snakemake < 6 but succeeds on 6.0.0 on my Ubuntu machine:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'output.txt',

rule one:
    output:
        'output.txt',
    params:
        x= list(range(0, 1000000))
    shell:
        r"""
        echo {params.x} > {output}
        """
```