# One of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!: Works on a dummy set

Tags: snakemake

I have just plunged into snakemake pipeline building so maybe I am missing something crucial but to the point:

I've assembled a few steps and on a dummy input, I've tested it locally with success.
Then I tried to run the code on a cluster through `qsub` but that seems to fail (this is mostly me not reading enough about it, I am sure) BUT I can run the pipeline on a cluster as an interactive session.

The previous step in the pipeline generates 'kmer counts'. And then this step combines all the files in the input into a single tabular file by means of R's `map()` function and some tidyverse transformations.
The dummy case, where I just truncate the input `sample_PH=PH_list[:20]` seems to execute, the R session is started and the STDOUT messages are generated.

But giving the full list (8k+ samples) seems to fail with the "non-zero exit " code.

I am not sure why I'm seeing this behaviour. For this step the total memory size of files is 5GB but my interactive node runs at a much higher memory capacity of 200GB.

Any experience in what might be causing this error as I don't know where to start?

Thank you in advance.

```
rule join_PH_whole:
    input:
        expand(
            "1_data/kma_clustering_{sim}/01_kmc/PATRIC_phage/seq_whole/{kmer}_mer/{sample_PH}.{kmer}_mer.kms",
            sample_PH=PH_list, kmer=KMERS, sim=SIMS)
    output:
        "1_data/kma_clustering_{sim}/02_kmc_joints/PATRIC_phage/seq_whole/{kmer}_mer_kmc_agg.tsv"
    params:
        out_dir = "1_data/kma_clustering_{sim}/02_kmc_joints/PATRIC_phage/seq_whole",
        kmer = "{kmer}",
        origin = "-1"
    shell:
        "Rscript scripts/combine_full_seq_kmc_output.R {params.out_dir} {params.kmer} {params.origin} {input}"
```

Comment: Could be the number of [input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073269/snakemake-cannot-handle-very-long-command-line).  Can you use a [script directive](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts)? I don't think that has the same limitations.

Comment: non-zero exit code is not very specific, what is the actual exit code, maybe provide the full traceback?