# how to search for files in a directory containing mulitple strings in linux

Tags: linux, grep

There is a directory containing several files and i want to grep for files containing a string "str1" say. for this, the following cmd works perfectly fine :

```
 grep "str1" -r *
```

Now, i want to grep for files which contain two strings say `str1` and `str2`. can anyone please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Agree with what [Theolodis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1907026/theolodis) said: "you could have googled yourself ;)"

Comment: this approach which theolodis told didnt work for me. i had already googled and when i couldn't get the answer,i asked on this forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep "str1" -r -l *` Will print just the list of file names of the files with matches so

```
grep str2 `grep "str1" -r -l *`
```

Should do the job by supplying that lists as the file names input to grep.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864316/how-to-pipe-list-of-files-returned-by-find-command-to-cat-to-view-all-the-files) for the refresher on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "grep -q str1 {} && grep -q str2 {} && echo {}" \;
```

This would return all files in the current directory (and subdirectories) that contain both `str1` and `str2`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to join the sorted result of two calls to "grep -l"

```
join <(grep -l "str1" * | sort) <(grep -l "str2" * | sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "str1" -r * | grep "str2"
```

this will solve your problem... you could have googled yourself ;)

Comment: I had already tried the above approach, this doesn't work. The output for search of single string say "str1" comes like :     Binary file ./webcrome1.pcap matches
Binary file ./webcrome2.pcap matches
Binary file ./webcrome3.pcap matches

Comment: @Theolodis LMGTFY links are considered [a little rude](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links/15660#15660) on SO, and your question gets the point across without it.

Comment: @Chilledrat removed it

Comment: This only works if both `str1` and `str2` are on the *same line*. I don't think that's what is asked for.

Comment: Unfortunately this will only match lines that contain both `"str12"` and `"str2"` as the input for the second grep will be the matching lines from the first.